# Swift generic T.Type becomes T.Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

Swift 5.1

I'm writing a class that has a generic parameter `T`, and one of its methods accepts a type as an argument, where the type extends from `T.Type`.  See `foo1` below:

```
public protocol P {
}

public class C: P {
}

public class X<T> {
    public func foo1(_ t: T.Type) { // The function in question
    }

    public func foo2(_ t: P.Type) {  // Note that this works as expected, but is not generic
    }
}

public func test() {
    let x = X<P>()
    x.foo1(C.self) // ERROR Cannot convert value of type 'C.Type' to expected argument type 'P.Protocol'
    x.foo2(C.self) // Works as expected, but is not generic
}
```

Now, `foo1` works fine when `T` is a class.  However, when `T` is a protocol (e.g. `P`), Swift seems to rewrite my function signature from `T.Type` to `T.Protocol`.

1. Why did it do this?
2. How do I instead get `foo1` to accept a type that inherits from `P`?

Class `X` is used in a number of other places - any changes to it must not restrict or remove class parameter `T` nor reduce `X`'s functionality, nor make explicit reference to `C` or `P`.  (It would be acceptable to constrain `T` to exclude protocols that do not extend `AnyObject`; I don't know how to do that, though.  It might also be acceptable to e.g. create a subclass of `X` that adds the ability to handle a protocol in `T`, but I'm not sure how to do that, either.)

For clarity, this class is used to register classes (`t`) that conform to some specified parent (`T`), for more complicated project reasons.  (Note that classes are being registered, not instances thereof.)  The parent is given at the creation of `X`, via the type parameter.  It works fine for a `T` of any class, but I'd also like it to work for a `T` of any protocol - or at least for a `T` of any protocol `P: AnyObject`, under which circumstances `foo1` should accept any subclass of `P`...the same way it works when `T` is a class.

Comment: what if you write let x = X<C>()
    x.foo1(C.self) // OK
    x.foo2(C.self)

Comment: `func foo1<T>(_ t: T.Type) where T: P { `

Comment: @jawadAli Well, because I'd also like `foo1(C2.self)` to work for the same instance of `X`, where `C2: P`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, I tried to list all the constraints, but I guess while I specified that `C` could not be explicitly used in `X`, I did not think to specify that `P` could not explicitly be used.  I've updated my question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `C` *is a* `P`, but `C.Type != P.Type`, so the error.

But generics works in a bit different way, like in below examples:

```
public class X {
    public func foo1<T>(_ t: T.Type) { // this way
    }

    public func foo3<T:P>(_ t: T.Type) { // or this way
    }

    public func foo2(_ t: P.Type) {  // Note that this works as expected, but is not generic
    }
}

public func test() {
    let x = X()
    x.foo1(C.self) // << works
    x.foo3(C.self) // << works
    x.foo2(C.self) // Works as expected, but is not generic
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first line - instead, `C` is a `P`, and `C.Type` is a `P.Type`, but `C.Type` is NOT a `P.Protocol`, and for some reason Swift is doing the third check instead of the second check.  Unfortunately, I'd much rather not remove the generic parameter from the class, because `X` is designed to work with a _subset_ of all classes (which subset is specified at the instantiation of `X`).  I lose a lot of type safety if I get rid of the class's generic parameter.  I've added an explanation to the end of my question, which is probably clearer.